# Make a query that hits the DB and then make others from it without hitting

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a process that needs to make multiple queries, but all of them have something in common so I tried to optimize it by making a bigger query just once that will have all the information and then make sub-queries from it. The problem is when I check at the sql executed it's still hitting the DB for each sub-query.

First I must ask if this is possible with Django in the current version and if it's possible in older versions (Got and app in 1.4.x) and how would I do it?

The logic is more complex than this, it has another for with another object but the idea is the following:

```
#I need it to hit the db here:
big_query = MyModel.objects.filter(something = something)

for object in another_model_query_set:
   ...
   #I need it not to hit the db here:
   sub_query = big_query.filter(another_something = object.something)
   ...
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to hit the database again, and you're sure that all your data is included in the first query, you'll need to do the filtering in pure Python.

```
sub_query = [obj for obj in big_query if obj.something = another_something]
```

and so on. Note that this returns a list rather than a queryset, and you won't be able to use any of the standard queryset methods like sort; again, you'd need to do that with the standard Python sorting methods.

Comment: I think that should be `[obj for obj in big_query if obj.another_something == object.something]`.

Comment: Since I had no django way to do it I did something similar with pure python, but creating a dictionary instead so I could access more efficiently. Still I'd like to wait and see if someone gives me another answer using querysets.

Answer (score 0):

if you havenot read yet [about Queryset evaluation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/optimization/#understand-queryset-evaluation):

**Template**

you can use `with` to cache the queryset and loop over it without hitting the db.

```
{% with cached_queryset=object.related_name.all %}
   {% for object in cached_queryset %}
      {# no db hit #}
      todo
   {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

**Views**

you can use generators, it is just awesome, [this is priceless tutorial](http://www.file-upload.net/download-9949251/Generators.pdf.html)

```
sub_query = [obj for obj in big_query if obj.something == another_something]
```

(copied from Daniel)

Comment: I only need it in the views, so I did something similar using only python.